# My thread acquires the read lock but when trying to release it IllegalMonitorStateException is thrown

Tags: java, exception, reentrantreadwritelock

my application is deployed on Weblogic 10.3.5 with java 6 update 30. I encountered with the following error while executed this code lines:

```
    lock.readLock().lock();
    try {
        holder = cache.get(configName);
        // If it exists in the cache, return it
        if (holder != null)
            return holder;
    } finally {
        lock.readLock().unlock();
    }
```

while lock is initialized during class loading:

```
private final ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
```

cache is:

```
private Map<String, ConfigurationHolder> cache = new HashMap<String,ConfigurationHolder>();
```

Suddenly IllegalMonitorStateException were thrown:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$Sync.tryReleaseShared(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:363)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.releaseShared(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1317)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$ReadLock.unlock(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:745)
```

I read [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7099601) similar description to this scenario.

Anyone have any idea why this is happen?

Comment: is it possible that one of those calls inside the try block is incorrectly releasing the lock?

Comment: It could be a bug in the JVM, can you try a more recent update of Java?

Comment: no, because cache object is a Map.

Comment: Is it possible that another thread has released the lock, too? Your snippet does not show what other code might access lock.

If I'm right, an IllegalMonitorStateException is only thrown when releasing a lock that you don't own, or is no longer there.